# How to unset range of array in Bash

Tags: bash, array

I'm trying to delete range of array element but it's fail..

My array

```
root@ubuntu:~/work# echo ${a[@]}
cocacola.com airtel.com pepsi.com
```

Print 0-1 array looks ok

```
root@ubuntu:~/work# echo ${a[@]::2}
cocacola.com airtel.com
```

Now I'm trying to delete only these element using :

```
root@ubuntu:~/work# unset a[@]::2
root@ubuntu:~/work# echo ${a[@]}
```

It's delete whole array..

What I'm doing wrong ?

I found other way of deleting range of array but why above things is not working ?

```
for ((i=0; i<2; i++)); do unset a[$i]; done
```

EDIT
I had also tried but no luck

```
unset -v 'a[@]::2'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One thing to bear in mind is that `bash` implemented arrays like `ksh`, that is as associative arrays where keys are limited to positive integers (contrary to other languages like `perl` or `zsh` for instance).

In:

```
a[123]=foo a[456]=bar a[789]=baz
```

In bash, you've got an associative array with 3 elements, while in `perl`, you'd have an array with 790 elements (789 with zsh).

In `ksh` or `bash`, `${a[@]:0:1}` returns the first element of the array in the list of elements sorted numerically by key where the key is greater or equal to 0. So in that case, it returns `${a[123]}`, not `${a[0]}`.

```
unset 'a[123]'
```

(remember to quote it, otherwise it would fail if there was a file called a1 or a2 or a3 in the current directory) makes sense, as it removes a particular key in the array.

```
unset 'a[@]::2'
```

makes less sense though. `bash` only understands `unset a`, `unset 'a[123]'` or `unset 'a[*/@]'`, anything after is ignored, so `unset 'a[@]::2'` and `unset 'a[@]please'` do the same: unset the whole array.

If you want to unset a range of keys, you'd need to loop through the keys:

To get the list of keys of the array, the syntax is `"${!a[@]}"`. Unfortunately, applying a range to that doesn't work with `bash` nor `ksh`, so you'd need a temporary array:

```
keys=("${!a[@]}")
for i in "${keys[@]::2}"; do unset "a[$i]"; done
```

Now if you want to consider those arrays like in other languages, you don't want to use `unset`. Like, if the array is not sparse in the first place and you want to keep it so (that is shift all the elements by 2 instead of unsetting the first two), you can do things like:

```
a=("${a[@]:2}")
```

That is reassign the array with the list of elements you want to keep.

For comparison, with `zsh`.

```
a=({1..20})
unset 'a[12,16]'
```

would set an empty value to elements 12 to 16. while `unset 'a[16,20]'` would shrink the array to 15 elements.

```
a=({1..20})
a[12,16]=()
```

(still with `zsh`) would shift elements 17 to 20 by 5 positions so `a[12]` would contain `17`.

Comment: Thanks.. you are my master... with help of this , I have solve one problem.. so please have look at this and let me if any improvement in that Bash Code .. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74001/scripting-to-domain-allocation-to-server/74211#74211

Answer (score 2):

1. If your array is **continuous/not sparse** (all elements from 0..N-1 set)

   You can remove the 2nd element of the array with

   ```
   unset 'a[1]'
   ```

   To remove the 2nd, 3rd and 4th element, you can use e.g.

   ```
   for ((i=1; i<=3; i++)); do unset "a[$i]"; done
   ```

   To delete all but the 1st and 2nd element, you can use e.g.

   ```
   for ((i=2; i<${#a[@]}; i++)); do unset "a[$i]"; done
   ```
2. **General solution** (works also for sparse arrays):
   You can remove the 2nd element of the array with

   ```
   unset "a[$(echo ${!a[@]} | cut -d" " -f 2)]"
   ```

   To remove the 2nd, 3rd and 4th element, you can use e.g.

   ```
   for $(echo ${!a[@]} | cut -d" " -f 2-4) ; do unset "a[$i]"; done
   ```

   To delete all but the 1st and 2nd element, you can use e.g.

   ```
   for $(echo ${!a[@]} | cut -d" " -f 2-) ; do unset "a[$i]"; done
   ```

Comment: I already did this n had updated in question.. but question remain about `unset a[@]::2`

Comment: That's wrong in the general case because `${#a[@]}` is the number of elements in the array, not the greatest indice in the array (`bash` arrays, like `ksh` arrays are sparse, contrary to zsh ones).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas after deleting element why not reset index ?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas after doing some RnD I Found this way to reset array `a=( $(echo ${a[@]})  )`  is this fine ?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I fixed my answer for sparse arrays, but your answer is more clean.

Comment: @RahulPatil, if you want to _unsparse_ the array, just write it: `a=("${a[@]}")`, using `echo` and command substitution would only work in limited corner cases (like when none of the elements are empty or contain spc, tab, NL, backslash, *, ?, [ or start with -).